# Fluent NHibernate HasManyToMany() Save/Update Problem

Tags: orm, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, mapping, fluent

i have the following code, which is supposed to give specific functionality but it isn't :S

anyway, here's my problem:

http://img525.imageshack.us/img525/1315/diagramp.png

here's the mapping code:

```
public class UsersMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UsersMap()
    {

        this.Table("Users");
        Id(x => x.UserName).GeneratedBy.Assigned();

        Map(x => x.FirstName);
        Map(x => x.LastName);
        Map(x => x.Password);
        Map(x =>x.EMail);
        Map(x => x.Title);
        Map(x => x.Division);
        Map(x => x.Status);

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Roles)
            .Table("UserInRoles").ParentKeyColumn("Username")
            .ChildKeyColumn("RoleId").AsBag().Inverse();


    }
}

public class RolesMap : ClassMap<Role>
{

    public RolesMap()
    {
        this.Table("Roles");
        Id(x => x.ID).GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.RoleName);

        HasManyToMany(x => x.Users)
            .Table("UserInRoles").ParentKeyColumn("RoleId")
            .ChildKeyColumn("Username").AsBag().Cascade.All();

    }


}
```

my problem is when trying to (assign a Role for specific user) the UserName is added to table UserInRoles but the Role ID if it is already existing it will be removed from its corrosponding row and assigned to the new row, any idea ?

Comment: sorry for the picture that it is small, i didnt notice that which posting :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked making your [ManyToMany work by convention](http://legeronline.blogspot.com/2009/08/sarp-architecture-part-1-implementing.html)?

Linked example actually refers to Roles and pretty much what you are trying to do here.

Comment: Thank you, but it seems the same issue after making some changes ( as in the link you posted).